# PC is slow - why?

Tags: windows-10, cpu

I'm using a PC which seems like it should be fairly good (although now old) going by the spec.  It seems like it should be more than able to handle what use it for anyway, but it's struggling and I wonder if you might have any idea why.

This is the spec:

Processor: AMD FX(tm)-8120 Eight-Core Processor 3.10 GHz
GPU: GeForce GTX 650
RAM: 8GB
Windows 10

Although when it comes to playing Overwatch it has in the past often lost the rendering device, in general it renders better (more quickly) than a much newer laptop in the house for games like Overwatch and WoW.

However for simple functions, like using a web browser or the Windows search box whilst playing Hearthstone, it can freeze and often has frozen for 5 mins or so.  I'm just wondering if there may be a relatively simple fix for this issue or might it be the case that the only fix is upgrading the GPU or PSU?

By the way, I plan to try a possible fix suggested in response to a very similar question which is to disable various options under Exploit Protection in Settings.

Comment: find it somewhat ironic and ridiculous that my question has been closed on the grounds that it needs 'details or clarity' when it is perfectly clear and no indication whatsoever has been given of which details ought to be added or in which way/s it is unclear, the very fault I've been falsely accused of by whomsoever closed the question! This sort of unhelpful, awkward response is far too common on this family of websites for my liking.

Answer (score -1):

It might be a number of issues. You could try for starters giving software maintenance to your pc. If you have Windows, I recommend [Ashampoo Windows Optimizer](https://www.ashampoo.com/en/eur/pin/5806/system-utilities/winoptimizer-free?download-eid=34262). But if you don't mind intrusive terms of service, specially regarding privacy, you can try [Tune Up Utilities](https://www.avg.com/en-us/avg-pctuneup#pc), which is what I used many years ago.

You can try also running antivirus and antimalware programs to see if your pc is infected. For Windows, I recommend [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/). I don't have a recommendation for antivirus, because the newer version of Windows Defender is pretty good. I don't know how an older one is though. You could try [ESET](https://www.eset.com/us/home/online-scanner/) for example, which has both online scanner and a download version. But I don't remember its terms of service.

Another reason why your pc is sluggish is because it may have remote access software which is not necessarily regarded as malware or virus so it might not be detected by the above. Someone with access to your pc might have installed it or maybe a hacker remotely install it. I'm not sure how to detect it though, but it is removed if you reinstall windows, which could be tricky if you don't know what you are doing.

Regarding hardware, if your pc is old, maybe your hard disk is failing and that's why it's sluggish. If it has errors that cannot be fixed that a sure sign it is failing. I recommend you back up all your info before it finally fails. Another item that might be failing is the processor. If you haven't given hardware maintenance to your pc,  probably the fan is full of dust and the thermal paste has worn out, heating the processor too much and causing performance issues. I recommend checking if the fan is not blocked by dust and if you can't change the thermal paste, I recommend using a cooling pad if you are using a laptop or a floor fan if you are using a desktop, if it has enough vents for the air to go through it. Or maybe you would be able to remove the side panel that gives access to the inside so the air can go in and cool your pc.

Finally that I can think of, check if you have enough ram (I recommend at least 4 or 8 gigas of RAM) or if your graphics card is good enough for current programs or if it meets the requirements of your operating system.

Comment: I don't think it's the fan as I checked the fan shortly after the problem began and it was fine. I actually think it may be that the PSU and/or GPU need upgrades, but most likely the PSU isn't powerful enough.  This said, I did try the fix I mentioned and so far there has been a substantial improvement, but I still think upgrading the PSU might solve the issue completely. I would say thanks for your reply but this is discouraged for some strange reason.  This family of websites has a number of strange and silly things about it, I must say. Shame because it's a helpful group of forums at times.

Comment: Wasn't me who downvoted your answer by the way.

Comment: Yeah, I don't like how often they suspend or close questions. Glad your pc doing better.

Comment: It's crazy, right?  These people think they're so clever though xD